# Automatic cropping of collimated digital X-ray images

Tags: imaging, software

Do you have any suggestions for a library which offers an algorithm to crop digital X-ray images automatically?

We receive full-size images (43x43cm) from a detector, independent of the collimator settings. If the collimator has been closed to 10x15cm, we need to crop this area. This should be done automatically, so that the user does not even see the full-size image because it contains a lot of information which is not needed.

Now we are looking for a good library which offers such an algorithm. This sounds like a simple task, but depending on the dose and the collimation, it can be pretty hard to detect the collimated area of the image. Therefore, we are looking for a professional solution rather than implementing it ourselves.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you looking for libraries if you do not want to implement the software yourselves??? Are you rather looking for some premade software?

Answer (score 4):

There is a software package ImageJ which can be used to what you are asking. Depending on your capability and the complexity of what you are doing you can either write a Macro in the program to crop images or you can extend the program in Java and write a custom plugin to do what you describe.

I used this program for years it is a very strong program.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but... *"we are looking for a professional solution rather than implementing it ourselves"*.

Comment: I think ImageJ is actually the best option. You can pay a freelance developer to write the macro for you: it does not seems a big task the way you describe it

Comment: I second the recommendation for ImageJ. It's not difficult to write a simple macro (or a developer to do so) to crop an image. The nice thing about ImageJ (and I would recommend using the updated Fiji software at http://fiji.sc ) is that it is open source and used heavily for many biological science needs. If it works for microscopy, it'll work for x-ray imaging.